# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sylvia/Documents/Profile/build'

Tags: javascript, github, vite

I am trying to deploy this to Github pages https://github.com/SylviaMakuch/Profile. However, Im getting this message :ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sylvia/Documents/Profile/build.

I've tried to update dependencies, uninstall to re-install. I've also tried to use Vite for the first time in this- perhaps it's a vite issue?

I have no clue what's happening.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems vite is trying to target a directory that doesn't exist, you may want to setup a `vite.config.js` file, and set it to target your dist directory https://vitejs.dev/config/